# what is the proper way to call get request with passing json request parameter?

Tags: android, http, http-headers

I want to call http request using get method with passing json parameter to get request call.so what will be the proper way to call http get method with passing json request.

Comment: GET *usually* doesn't take a request body. Don't try unless you control client, server, and the full path between.

Answer (score 0):

http://plaincodesource.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-post.html try this. I believe you can set reauest method "GET" and then write your json into output stream.